# What keeps the private key safe if an attacker has both clear and encrypted copies of a message and the public key?

Tags: cryptography, cryptanalysis, asymmetric

Let's say someone obtained a message in both clear text and in its encrypted copy with asymmetric cryptography, like RSA-2048. He also has the public keys.

Is the private key still undiscoverable? If yes, what property makes it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is known as a "known-plaintext" attack -  an excellent answer to this question can be found on the crypto stack exchange:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/is-a-known-plaintext-ciphertext-and-public-key-a-viable-attack-on-rsa.

Short and straight: it is not possible.